# A curve has the equation $y=x^3 - 4x^2 - 3x + 17$. What are the x-coordinates of the point(s) on this curve where the tangent is parallel to 4y=7x-11.

Tags: derivatives, algebraic-curves

A curve has the equation $$y=x^3 - 4x^2 - 3x + 17$$. What are the x-coordinates of the point(s) on this curve where the tangent is...

(a) parallel to $4y=7x-11$
(b) horizontal

Comment: Welcome Math.SE! Take the [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) using $LaTeX$ syntax. This appears to be a [homework question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question), please share your thoughts and attempts towards the solution. If you receive useful answers, consider [accepting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one.

Comment: What is the slope of the tangent to a curve ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

You already know that, at a point $x_0$, the slope of the tangent to a curve $y=f(x)$ is given by $m=f'(x_0)$.

In you case, you are given the slope, then you have to find the corresponding $x_0$. Since, in your problem, $f(x)$ is a cubic, $f'(x)$ is a quadratic and tou know how to solve a quadratic equation.

I am sure that you can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

(a) The slope of the line $4y = 7x - 11$ is $7/4$. To find the points on the curve $y=x^3 - 4x^2 - 3x +17$ that have tangents being parallel to this line, we must find values of $x$ for which the derivative is the same as the line's slope (i.e., equal to $7/4$). We will first find the derivative of the curve:
 $$\frac{dy}{dx} = 3x^2 - 8x - 3$$ 
Now we can equate this to our desired slope, and find the values of $x$ where the equation holds:

$$3x^2 - 8x - 3 = \frac{7}{4}$$
$$3x^2 - 8x - \frac{19}{4} = 0$$

Now we have a quadratic form which we can solve for $x$ by:
$$x_{1,2} = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

Solve for $x$ and we get $x_1 = 3.1667=\frac{19}{6},\ x_2=-0.5$.

(b) We will solve this in the exact same manner, except instead of looking for $x$ values with a $7/4$ tangent, we would like the tangent to be horizontal, i.e., having slope 0. Equating the derivative to 0 we get:
$$ 3x^2 - 8x - 3 = 0 $$

Again, a quadratic form. Solving for $x$ we get: $x_1 = -\frac{1}{3}$, $x_2=3$.